# PCP is still active after contribution page is disabled

Tags: civicontribute, pcp

The current behavior of civicrm keeps the PCP as active even if the contribution page related to it is disabled.

A real problem with this is you have someone who has made a P2P contribution page who might have no clue the page has been disabled by a site admin and is out promoting the page!

Thoughts on expected behavior?

- Disable PCP manually when CP is disabled.
- Keep PCP as it is and change the error message on PCP load.
- Disable the PCP and send an email notification to the creator.
- The current error is perhaps the correct and enough response to be shown to the user

Comment: That’s indeed an issue! I’m going to check if this is also the case w/ PCP Event pages.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to confirm this is also happening with Event PCPs - though the error message is a little easier on the eyes - which really helps (the red and black letters on the yellow background you get for 'not available' Contribution PCPs make it look like the site is broken).

[image]

Re: Answer as to what should happen may be different for Event PCPs vs Contribution PCPs - I'd be in favour that the PCP remain non-functional. Once you conclude an Event and have done your books/finances on it you want to be able to file it. Same with Contribution PCPs (which will often have a Campaign associated with it). There needs to be a date where you can say with confidence: this Event or this Campaign raised $x;

So my vote would be for option 4 [a nicer error message] - you may be able to get that into Core without too many issues.

For our Event PCPs we use Views to get people to their nice looking PCP page - which then with a Donate button links to the donate page that will show the 'currently unavailable' message. That means we have the option to notify donors ahead of time that the Event/Campaign is no longer active by filtering out non-active Events in the View - and in addition: people are naturally promoting their nice looking PCP page - which remains active/functional. But there we could grey out the button.